# Javascript plugin and environment variables

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I was reading the documentation here https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript but cannot find a mention on how to make usage of environment variables in a  javascript plugin.

Currently I tried to put a .env file at the root of my plugin in custom/apps/MyPlugin/.env and to capture them via process.env but it fallbacks to my default values...

Is there a way to handle a .env file when you run `bash bin/build-storefront.sh`?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but their documentation mentions environment variables: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/tooling/cli/using-watchers#environment-variables

Comment: I tried both `APP_ENV=dev bash bin/build-storefront.sh` and `APP_ENV=prod bash bin/build-storefront.sh` but the compiler keeps running in production mode: `NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js`. Any idea?

Comment: Not really. I've never used Shopware, sorry.

Comment: But I found this blogpost: https://developers.shopware.com/blog/2018/01/23/how-to-use-environment-variables-for-plugin-configuration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it...

First [create a custom `webpack.config.js`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/extending-webpack) at `src/Resources/app/storefront/build`. Also in that `build` directory run `npm install dotenv`, as you will need it to parse your `.env` file.

Your `webpack.config.js` could then look like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js`);

module.exports = () => {
    // given you `.env` is located directly in your plugin root dir
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../../../../../.env`);
    const config = dotenv.parse(contents);

    return {
        externals: {
            myPluginEnv: JSON.stringify(config),
        }
    };
};
```

Then inside your sources you can import `myPluginEnv`.

```js
import * as myPluginEnv from 'myPluginEnv';

/*
 * Example .env content:
 * FOO=1
 * BAR=1
 */

console.log(myPluginEnv);
// {FOO: '1', BAR: '1'}
```