# Extending Webpack - Is it cloud compatible?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I asked this question here: [Javascript plugin and environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388425/javascript-plugin-and-environment-variables)

While the solution is perfectly working in a dev (self-hosted Shopware) environment I would like to know if it will be working in the Shopware cloud environment. What should I consider when archiving the app before submission? Should the "dist" and "build" directories and the ".env" file be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to publish your plugin/app, you must include the pre-compiled assets within the `dist` directory in the archive. This is not only required for cloud hosted but for all production environments in general, as nodejs is not a requirement on production servers, so you can't expect the users to compile your sources. You should include all of your sources (`src` and `build` directory and in your specific case the `.env` file) nonetheless, just in case they do want to re-compile the assets at some point.